# Output buffering between methods

Tags: php, oop, output-buffering

I am trying to get output buffering to persist through initializing a class and outputting the results of that class like shown below

```
class test { 
   function __construct(){
      ob_start();
   }  

   public function create(){
      echo '<div>';
      ob_flush();
      echo '</div>';
   }
}


$obj = new test();
echo 'hello';
$obj->create();
```

output

```
  <div>
  hello
  </div>
```

I want to have what is echoed between the object put into its output buffer. How would I go about doing something similar to this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: By "put into it's output buffer", do you mean sent to the client through the response stream (.net term here, sorry)?

Comment: I am trying to save all output into the output buffer then put that into a div. This class is suppose to wrap output in a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you want something like this ([**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/x7eas6))

```
class test { 
    function __construct(){
      ob_start();
    }  

    public function create(){
      $data=ob_get_clean();
      echo "<div style='color:red;'>".$data."</div>";
    }
}

$obj = new test();
echo 'hello';
$obj->create();
```